# Visual Studio: step into assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, step-into

I have a project that references an assembly that I have the code to.  I also have all of the PDB files, etc.  However, at some point I clicked the wrong button on a dialog box while debugging, and now I can no longer step into the assembly code.  I know this description is a bit vague, but I believe that the dialog that I accidentally clicked through was the one that complains when your "source code is newer than the built version of the assembly, continue debugging?" but I can't be sure.  At any rate, I am positive that there is some easy way to get Visual Studio back in a state where it will start stepping through my assembly code again.  Any great ideas?

Comment: Hmm, sounds wrong.  It is stored in the hidden .suo file in the solution directory, you can delete it without too much pain.  Switching to assembly before the call would be another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure the following in your child project:-

- "build clean" your child project. please ensure that all dll and pdb files have been deleted from the bin\debug folder in your child project.
- "build" your child project by clicking build or ctrl-shift-b. Please do not hit F5 as for some reason it does not get the latest dll and pdb file.
- please ensure that you do not have a reference to the "Release" build of the parent dll, sometimes it has caused problems for me depending on the release build configuration for that project. It should be the "Debug" build configuration for the parent project and you should add reference from the debug folder or use "Reference Path" in visual studio.

Now you can run the project by hitting F5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that basically did it.  It seems that the final solution was to delete EVERYTHING that was related, and rebuild it all from scratch.  Not a real answer, but I guess that it works...

Comment: I think everytime you build your parent project, you need to ctrl-shift-b build the child project to get the new dll and pdb file. If you just hit F5 it will not update the dll. I asked you to clean dlls just in case something else was bad. But you don't need to clean everytime - you just need to do the non-F5 build.

Comment: Yeah, I almost always do that, and I have never had a problem before.  I guess something just got goofed along the way.  There are a lot of moving parts in these systems anyway...